# Send button on contact form does not work

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, button, sendgrid

Issue: I am encountering a problem while creating a contact form for a website. The form should send the entered data to a specific email address using the SendGrid module. However, when I click the "Send" button, I receive a 404 error in the console, and the email is not sent. The error message is as follows:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/send-email 404 (Not Found)
Card.tsx:58 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
```

Code: I have a Card.tsx file representing the contact form on the client-side. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import cardcss from "./Card.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

interface CardProps {
  imageUrl: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

function Card(props: CardProps) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const nameInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const emailInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const messageInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (messageInputRef.current) {
      messageInputRef.current.focus();
      messageInputRef.current.setSelectionRange(0, 0);

      // Delay setting the cursor position
      setTimeout(() => {
        messageInputRef.current?.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
      }, 0);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleFocus = (event: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.target.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  };

  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (
      nameInputRef.current &&
      emailInputRef.current &&
      messageInputRef.current
    ) {
      const nameInput = nameInputRef.current.value;
      const emailInput = emailInputRef.current.value;
      const messageInput = messageInputRef.current.value;

      const contactData = {
        Name: nameInput,
        Email: emailInput,
        Message: messageInput,
      };

      axios
        .post("/send-email", contactData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Received email request");
          // Handle success response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          // Handle error response
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={cardcss.cardcontainer}>
      <div className={cardcss.imagecontainer}>
        <img src={props.imageUrl} alt="" />
      </div>

      <div className={cardcss.cardtitle}>
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
      </div>

      <div className={cardcss.cardbody}>
        <p>{props.body}</p>

        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <div>
            <label className={cardcss.namelabel} htmlFor="name">
              Name:
            </label>
            <input
              className={cardcss.nameinput}
              type="text"
              id="name"
              name="name"
              ref={nameInputRef}
            />
          </div>

          <div className={cardcss.emailcontainer}>
            <label className={cardcss.emaillabel} htmlFor="email">
              Email:
            </label>
            <input
              className={cardcss.emailinput}
              type="text"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              ref={emailInputRef}
            />
          </div>

          <div className={cardcss.messagecontainer}>
            <label className={cardcss.messagelabel} htmlFor="message">
              Message:
            </label>
            <input
              ref={messageInputRef}
              className={cardcss.messageinput}
              type="text"
              id="message"
              name="message"
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              onFocus={handleFocus}
            />

            <button className={cardcss.sendbutton} type="submit">
              Send
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

And here is the server.js file responsible for handling the email sending on the server-side:

```
const express = require("express");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const { resolve } = require("path-browserify");

// Set up SendGrid API key
sgMail.setApiKey(
  "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"
);

// Create Express app
const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello, server!");
});
// Route to handle sending emails
app.post("/send-email", (req, res) => {
  const { Name, Email, Message, submitbutton } = req.body;

  const msg = {
    to: "paristiffany12@gmail.com",
    from: "paristiffany12@gmail.com",
    subject: "Example Subject",
    text: `Name: ${Name}\nEmail: ${Email}\nMessage: ${Message}\nSubmit Button: ${submitbutton}`,
    html: `<p>Name: ${Name}</p><p>Email: ${Email}</p><p>Message: ${Message}</p><p>Submit Button: ${submitbutton}</p>`,
  };

  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent successfully" });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.toString());
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to send email" });
    });
});

// Set up fallback for path module
resolve.fallback = { path: require.resolve("path-browserify") };

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

What I've Tried: I have verified that the SendGrid API key is correctly set up. Both the client and server are running locally. The server is listening on port 3000, and the client is making a POST request to http://localhost:3000/send-email. I have double-checked the server-side code and ensured that the /send-email route is properly defined. I have also confirmed that the form data is correctly retrieved and prepared before making the POST request.

Question: What could be causing the 404 error when attempting to send the email using the SendGrid module? Is there something wrong with my code or configuration? Any help would be greatly appreciated.